# htaccess SEO URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm a bit stumped here. I must have been over 100 articles and posts searching for a solution for this.

I'm trying to turn this:

```
sub.domain.org/folder/index.php?p=home
```

Into:

```
sub.domain.org/folder/home/
```

My Rule below have evolved many times but almost everything does not work. I don't know what else to try. Would really appreciate some help here. Mod Rewrite is enabled, and I'm hosting my own server.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?folder/(.*)/$ /folder/index\.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: "almost everythong does not work" - can you give an example what worked? And what does happen with your current rule, error 500 or 404 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code in `/folder/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?p=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Wow! That almost completely works. Now the images do not load on the page. I have all my images in subfolder `folder/img/logo.png` when using the rule, it turns into `folder/home/img/logo.png` which prevents the images from loading.

Comment: Actually that is not due to rule but due to the fact that you're using relative links for images. You can just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`. OR else You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/folder/" />`

Answer (score 0):

I think right regex is

```
RewriteRule ^/folder/(.*)/?$ /folder/index\.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+folder/index\.php\?p=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /folder/%1/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^folder/(.+)/?$ /folder/index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Your rule causes a loop and will return a 500 error.

Comment: That does not work. It redirects to the SEO url but i get a 404 page.

Comment: @Err does the part after "folder" have slashes in it?

Comment: Yes. It does. Still 404.

Comment: @err then you need to change the `[^/]` to `.` (see above)

Comment: Made the change, and I still get the 404 page. I'm using a copy/paste from your code and changing the folder name to the correct one. That's it.